# Como usar o atributo pattern?

Tags: html5, formulário

Já revirei a internet, até no W3school, e só vejo eles informando o código "pronto". Com chaves, interrogações, barras, cifrão e vários outros parâmetros.

Mas não encontrei nada explicando como utilizar esses parâmetros, pra que serve eles?

Comment: W3School definitivamente não é um dos lugares que eu recomendaria para estudar. É um site que ficou famoso pela falta de qualidade nas informações (e se fosse coisa boa, não precisava tentar se apropriar indevidamente do nome W3, que não tem relação nenhuma com eles). Isto posto, o que você tem que pesquisar é o RegEx do JavaScript, (expressões regulares), que é o padrão usado na validação por `pattern`. Veja o link da MDN sobre o assunto https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern

Comment: Mais especificamente, a sintaxe do RegEx usado está aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O atributo `pattern` nos formulários em HTML 5 permitem que aquele formulário seja validado através de uma [Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular).

As expressões regulares são um forma de validar expressões textuais que seguem algum tipo de padrão e ao aplicar essa expressão dentro do parâmetro `pattern` o HTML vai garantir que esse padrão é satisfeito.

**Exemplo:**

Você tem um formulário que precisa receber a placa de um carro. Esse tipo de informação no Brasil segue um determinado padrão: 3 letras de A até Z, seguida de um traço e por fim 4 números de 0 até 9. É possível expressar isso no seguinte formulário:

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="placa">Placa: </label>
  <input type="text" name="website" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Antes de usar o atributo `pattern` é preciso de um entendimento de como trabalhar com expressões regulares. Segue abaixo alguns artigos que podem te ajudar:

- https://tableless.com.br/o-basico-sobre-expressoes-regulares/
- http://turing.com.br/material/regex/introducao.html
- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145