# Validar apenas número no input

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho esse html

```
<input formControlName="sGPTypeDeliveryId" type="text" placeholder="Tipo de Entrega" class="form-control" required="required" pattern="[0-9]+$">
```

usando o atributo pattern deveria funcionar, porém comigo não está funcionando. Como eu faço para permitir apenas número no input?

Comment: Porque não usa html5 `<input type="number">` ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [input somente numeros com jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187172/input-somente-numeros-com-jquery)

Comment: Detalhe, acredito que funciona, o problema é que o pattern não previne que o usuário digite números, ele só não permite o envio do formulário com números

Comment: Para impedir isso, só com JavaScript.

Comment: @sam eu deixei um -1 não somente pelo motivo de a pergunta não ser suficientemente clara, pois ele não diz o que exatamente "não funciona", mesmo que funcione perfeitamente como o esperado, mas também pelo usuário ser ativo no site mais de 4 anos, ser um dos que mais pergunta (talvez o segundo) e ainda assim perguntar desta maneira. Desde que sou ativo no site, vejo perguntas ruins dele, geralmente é orientado a editar, mas parece ainda não se esforçar para manter a qualidade do site.

Answer (score 5):

Seu problema é que o atributo `pattern` não serve para determinar que o `input` só vai aceitar que se escreva números dentro dele. O *pattern* serve para vc validar o `input`. Se ele tiver letras vai ser **inválido**, porém se forem apenas números será **válido**.

Veja o que diz a Mozilla sobre o atributo `pattern` do HTML5:

> Uma expressão regular usada para validar o valor do controle. O padrão
>   deve casar com o valor completo da entrada, não apenas uma parte. Use
>   o atributo title para descrever o padrão para ajudar o usuário. Este
>   atributo é aplicado quando o valor do atributo type é text, search,
>   tel, url ou email; caso contrário ele é ignorado. A linguagem da
>   expressão regular é a mesma do JavaScript. O padrão não deve estar
>   entre barras.

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

***Para mais esclarecimentos vc pode consultar essa pergunta:*** [Como usar o atributo pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182118/como-usar-o-atributo-pattern)

---

Exemplo prático de uso

Veja esse exemplo para entender melhor a validação com o *pattern* no *front* usando CSS. Repare que no `input` `type="number"` vc só consegue digitar números dentro. No outro que é `type="text"` ele só fica válido se vc digitar números, se forem letras ele continua com a borda vermelha :invalido.

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red !important;
}
input:valid {
  border-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Esse input só vai ser válido se tiver apenas números
<input formControlName="sGPTypeDeliveryId" type="text" placeholder="apenas números ou será inválido" class="form-control" required="required" pattern="[0-9]+$">
    
Esse input é do type="number" ele só deixa escrever números dentro
<input type="number" class="form-control" >
```

Answer (score 1):

No tipo do input é só colocar number. Fica assim:

```
<input formControlName="sGPTypeDeliveryId" type="number" placeholder="Tipo de Entrega" class="form-control" required="required">
```

Comment: neste caso o pattern é denecessário, não?

Comment: Sim, porque o pattern só é valido para os tipos: `text, date, search, url, tel, email, and password.` 
Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Obrigado pela observação

Answer (score 1):

Há duas formas de se obter o resultado com apenas HTML. A primeira usando [expressão regular](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) no atributo pattern e a segunda usando o [type number](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

```html
<form>
  <input formControlName="sGPTypeDeliveryId" type="text" placeholder="Tipo de Entrega" class="form-control" required="required" pattern="\d*">
  <input formControlName="sGPTypeDeliveryId" placeholder="Tipo de Entrega" class="form-control" required="required" type="number" step="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: O que ele usou na pergunta não foi uma expressão regular?