# Adaptar formatação do input

Tags: html, css

Tenho um input field onde quero que o usuário coloque a matrícula do carro no seguinte formato "11-22-dd ".

Como é que faço para que o formulário seja inválido caso o valor enviado não siga naquele formato especifico? 
Ou então, como faço para que o usuário seja obrigado a escrever naquele formato?

Comment: O elemento [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) possui o atributo `pattern` que você pode informar uma expressão regular para validar o valor do campo. Quer tentar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste link, é bem o que procura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182118/como-usar-o-atributo-pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar o atributo `pattern` e `required` (ambos HTML5). O `required` irá impedir o envio do formulário caso nada seja digitado no campo, e o `pattern` irá impedir o envio do formulário se o valor não seguir o padrão da expressão regular especificada.

Pelo que entendi, o formato seria 2 números + 2 números + duas letras minúsculas, separados por hífen. A expressão regular seria:

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{2}
```

Ficaria assim:

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{2}" required>
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

> Embora a regex no `pattern` exija que o valor do campo esteja no
>   formato especificado, o submit aceita o campo vazio, por isso é
>   necessário o `required` também.

### Validando com JavaScript

Outra forma é verificar o campo com JavaScript, sem usar os atributos do HTML5. A lógica é basicamente a mesma, basta verificar se o valor do campo atende a expressão regular. Neste caso, é preciso incluir na regex os delimitadores `^` (início da string) e `$` (fim da string), caso contrário aceitaria algo como `11-22-aas` ou `111-22-aa`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e){
      
      var campo = document.forms[0].registro.value;
      
      if(!/^\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{2}$/.test(campo)){
         e.preventDefault(); // aborta o submit
         alert("Valor inválido");
      }
      
   }
   
});
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" name="registro">
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: É importante o uso do `Placeholder` para mostrar para o usuário que existe uma máscara a ser respeitada.

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é usar o plugin `jquery mask`, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.placa').mask('00-00-AA');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>


<input class="placa">
```

Comment: Talvez ele não esteja utilizando jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Com a biblioteca [Jquery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) você pode ter uma interação bem melhor que a do HTML5 com o `pattern` pois aí você não avisa o usuário que tem um máscara.

Já com a biblioteca fica um IHC bem melhor:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data').mask('dd-mm-aa');
    })

   <input id="data" placeholder="dd-mm-aa">
```

> Importante usar o Placeholder pra mostrar como seria a máscara.